# Add class in Jade template

Tags: pug

I have a header included in a Jade page, and use it for navigation. Among others I have this list:

```
ul
  li foo
  li bar
  li baz
```

Now there's the pages using the header:

```
html
  body
   include includes/head
     .main
        p This page is about bar
```

How can I add a class "active" to the li bar in the header?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jade: Change active menu item in parent template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719660/jade-change-active-menu-item-in-parent-template) Seems you both asked the same question on the same day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jade: Change active menu item in parent template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719660/jade-change-active-menu-item-in-parent-template)