# Jade: Change active menu item in parent template

Tags: html, pug

I have a navigation bar in my parent jade template and I'd like to highlight the item which is currently in view. So if I'm on the blog page,

```
ul
  li Home
  li.active Blog
  li Contact Us
  li About
```

Without copying the navigation bar structure into each child template, is there a way to have the parent template see what page it's extending and apply the `active` class accordingly?

Comment: javascript's your best bet

Comment: I disagree. I would repeat this structure in the child templates before I used a JS hack.

Comment: I just wanted to show what it'd look like if you were to inline everything. the code looks horrible

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/18214564/954777

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**parent.jade**

```
doctype 5

html
  block link
    -var selected = 'home'; //default

  -var menu = { 'home': '/home', 'blog': '/blog', 'contact': '/contact' };

  body
    nav
      ul
        each val, key in menu
          li
            if selected === key
              a.selected(href=val, title=key)= key
            else
              a(href=val, title=key)= key
```

**child.jade**

```
extends parent

block link
  -var selected = 'blog';
```

Comment: Really? There's no simpler way to do this? -sad face-

Comment: I am using PyJade, to get this to work i had to do "each val, key in menu.iteritems()" +1 for sure. Thanks

Comment: @Costa solution is simpler and more performant since is done with css no iteration, no if statement, no duplication of a tag

Comment: This solution is not easy to maintain because if you change your routes names, you have *also* to edit their definition in the template. @Costa solution in this way brings a more robust one.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simpler way:

Use this in your layout.jade (where `nav` is the name of the page that's active. nav = 'about' for example)

```
ul(class="#{nav}")
  li.home Home
  li.blog Blog
  li.contact Contact Us
  li.about About
```

Then put this is your CSS:

```
ul.home li.home,
ul.blog li.blog,
ul.contact li.contact,
ul.about li.about {
    color: red;
}
```

The only css rule that will apply is the one whose `ul` class exists. You'll need to pass in a variable `nav` that equals 'about', 'home', 'contact', or 'blog' depending on what page you're on.

Comment: If you're using Sass, you may also be able to do this: http://codepen.io/ajkochanowicz/pen/zGvgxz

Comment: Hey i did the same but in the inspector it says "undefined". I have my nav in a separate .jade-file (I'm new in jade  )

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @moesphemie - a bit late now, but make sure you're putting your "var nav= 'home'" definition inside the correct block in jade.

Answer (score 5):

Use the  [Current object](http://harpjs.com/docs/development/current) with a ternary expression. All is in the documentation.

You can use the object properties to generate your active menu like so. If you want to use folders in your navigation menu (Jade version) :

```js
ul(class="nav-menu")
            li: a(class="#{ current.path[0] === 'index' ? 'active' : '' }", href="/") home
            li: a(class="#{ current.path[0] === 'about' ? 'active' : '' }", href="/about/") about
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with current Jade:
`
    24|           #navbar.collapse.navbar-collapse
    25|             ul.nav.navbar-nav
  > 26|               li(class="#{ current.path[0] == 'index' ? 'active' : '' }")
    27|                 a(href='/') Main
    28|               li(class="#{ current.path[0] == 'sub' ? 'active' : '' }")
    29|                 a(href='#sub') Subscribe

Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
`

Answer (score 0):

Well, above solution is very clear but if someone is looking more controls over menus then there is a module available for node.js. Use this and you would have complete control over menus.

Use Case : When menus visibles based on roles

https://www.npmjs.com/package/active-menu