# Setting dynamic content on either server or client side

Tags: angularjs, pug, mean

I'm starting a MEAN app without prior experience. I was wondering whether there was any best practices about dynamic content such as highlighting active links from a layout or displaying the user's name.

There may be many different ways to do this, but I'm considering two here.

Using Pug (Jade):

[Jade: Change active menu item in parent template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719660/jade-change-active-menu-item-in-parent-template)

Using Angular:

[How to set bootstrap navbar active class with Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199418/how-do-i-implement-the-bootstrap-navbar-active-class-with-angular-js)

Does it make any difference at all?

Comment: Difference by what means? end result will be the same. This is a matter of responsibility. For example if you display the user's name and then he logs out: do you refresh the entire page causing a new render or do you want the change to happen without a page refresh (angular)?

Comment: That's a good point and it pretty much answers my question. Being the end result the same, Angular has the possibility to update the view without a page refresh. Now, I'm not sure whether the other option could have any advantage.

Comment: It does when you want the server to decide what the client can see. (Pages requiring authentication?)

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.